# Как выстроить элементы?

Tags: html, css

Есть div`ы, которые нужно выстроить сверху вниз в два ряда.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

в браузерах [поддерживающих nth-child](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child)

```
<div class="two_collumn">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>

</div>
test
```

CSS:

```
.two_collumn .cell {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    margin: 1px; 
    float: left;
}

.two_collumn .cell:nth-child(odd) {   
    clear: both;
}
.two_collumn:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "\a";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/zN4bM/

[здесь показано как сделать 3 или более колонок](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/zN4bM/2/)

Comment: вероятно ТС имеет в виду эффект от [CSS3 columns Property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp)

Comment: я его только что смотрел, у него один косяк, он div снизу, при некратном размере разбивает.

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/zN4bM/3/